# Handling WCF web config errors with MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, global-asax

I was about to use the following Application_Error() handling in my Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        Response.Clear();

        HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

        if (httpException != null)
        {
            string action;

            switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
            {
                case 404:
                    // page not found
                    action = "HttpError404";
                    break;
                case 500:
                    // server error
                    action = "HttpError500";
                    break;
                default:
                    action = "General";
                    break;
            }

            // clear error on server
            Server.ClearError();

            Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Error/{0}/?message={1}", action, exception.Message));
        }

    }
```

However, the issue was that I couldn't trap this error:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (100000) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

When I had the web.config value set to low, as when it got to the Response.Clear(); call, I get an HTTP exception:

> Response is not available in this context.

How can I get around this to handle all exceptions?

Thanks.